# Why does Django use `Meta` inner class in models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I want to describe some information such as ordering, if the model is proxy or abstract, which fields must be unique together, then I need to put this information in class named `Meta` that is inside of my model class. But if I want to change the manager I put information about it in the model class itself.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
         unique_together = ...
         ordering = ...
    objects = My manager()
```

Why did Django developers made such design decision (forcing to put some information about the model in the `Meta` inner class instead of the model class itself)? Why wouldn't they just let me put "ordering", "uniwue_tpgether" in the model class itself?

EDIT: Anentropic commented about it being a kind of namespacing. I thought about it while creating the question. If `Meta` inner class is a way of namespacing metainformation about the model so I'm free to create fields in the model class itself then why wasn't `objects` attribute put in the `Meta` class? There are many more attributes (`save`, `refresh_from_db`, `get_deffered_fields`, and [more](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L682)) that exist in the model class itself rather than in the `Meta` class that can collide with my field names if I dont know about them.

Comment: Probably as a form of namespacing, i.e. to leave the main body of the model class free for you to add your own fields, attributes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably to avoid conflicts with field names. For example, by putting `ordering` into the `Meta` class, you are still free to have a field named `ordering` on your model.

But then, why is the manager, named `objects` in the example, not in `Meta` as well? The reason is probably that you can access it as `Product.objects`, which is unlike any other `Meta` field. Moreover, the manager can have a custom name, for example `Product.products`.

You mentioned that there might also be conflicts with other class attributes besides meta fields, like methods. This is true, as [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/):

> Be careful not to choose field names that conflict with the [models API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/) like `clean`, `save`, or `delete`.

The risk of a conflict is quite small here, because methods usually have a verb in their name, like `save` or `get`, whereas field names are typically nouns, like `name`, `id` or `price`.